# How can i make a POST to a url

Tags: url, post, curl

I need to make a POST to a url with the parameter "data".

I tried using cURL, but i dont really understand it and there are no good tutorials about it.

any ideas?

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#POST

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Answer (score 0):

The poster Firefox plugin is pretty good. Is that the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: Never heard of it, i'm going to look it up, thanks for the comment